# KSQL SELECT code works, but CREATE TABLE `..` AS SELECT code returns error - io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlStatementException: Column cannot be resolved

Tags: confluent-platform, ksqldb

I've got a problem with creating a table or stream in KSQL.

I've made everything as shown in official examples and I don't get why my code does not work.
Example from https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/tutorials/examples.html#joining :

```
  CREATE TABLE pageviews_per_region_per_session AS
  SELECT regionid,
         windowStart(),
         windowEnd(),
         count(*)
  FROM pageviews_enriched
  WINDOW SESSION (60 SECONDS)
  GROUP BY regionid;
```

NOW MY CODE:

I've tried to run select in command prom and it WORKS WELL:

```
SELECT count(*) as attempts_count, "computer", (WINDOWSTART() / 1000) as row_time 
FROM LOG_FLATTENED 
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 20 SECONDS)
WHERE "event_id" = 4625
GROUP BY "computer" 
HAVING count(*) > 2;
```

But when I try to create the table based on this select (from ksql command-line tool):

```
CREATE TABLE `incorrect_logins` AS 
SELECT count(*) as attempts_count, "computer", (WINDOWSTART() / 1000) as row_time 
FROM LOG_FLATTENED 
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 20 SECONDS)
WHERE "event_id" = 4625
GROUP BY "computer" 
HAVING count(*) > 2;
```

I GET AN ERROR - `io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlStatementException: Column COMPUTER cannot be resolved.` But this column exists and select without `create table` statement works perfectly.

I'm using the latest stable KSQL image (`confluentinc/cp-ksql-server:5.3.1`)

Comment: There were recently lots of bugs fixed around quoted identifiers, which you seem to be leveraging quite heavily, but those fixes aren't available in the latest release (they're just on master at the moment). Can you try creating your streams and using only unquoted values for the column names and source names?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I've also tried without any quotes (this was my first option). But in the case without quotes, even the SELECT query does not work. I tried so:
SELECT count(*) as attempts_count, computer, (WINDOWSTART() / 1000) as row_time 
FROM LOG_FLATTENED 
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 20 SECONDS)
WHERE event_id = 4625
GROUP BY computer 
HAVING count(*) > 2; 
And get the same error io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlStatementException: Column ... cannot be resolved. When I write this query with quotes SELECT works but CREATE TABLE statement does not work.

Answer (score 1):

In first place, I apologize for my bad english, if something that I'll say it's not clear enough, do not hesitate to reply me and I try to explain me in a better way.

I don't know a lot of KSQL, but I'll try to help you, based on my experience creating STREAMS like your TABLE.

1) As you probably know, KSQL process everything as UpperCase unless you specify the opposite.

2) KSQL doesn't support double quotes in a SELECT inside a CREATE query, in fact, KSQL will ignore this characters and will handle your field as a UpperCase column, for that reason, in the error returned to you, appears **COMPUTER** and not "computer".

A **workaround** of this issue is:

- In first place, create an empty table with the lowerCase fields:

  CREATE TABLE "incorrect_logins" ("attempts_count" INTEGER, "computer" VARCHAR, "row_time" INTEGER) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='topic_that_you_want', VALUE_FORMAT='avro')

(If the topic doesn't exist, you'll have to create it before)

- Once the table has been created, you could insert data in the table using your SELECT query:

  INSERT INTO "incorrect_logins" SELECT count(*) as "attempts_count", "computer", (WINDOWSTART() / 1000) as "row_time" 
  FROM LOG_FLATTENED 
  WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 20 SECONDS)
  WHERE "event_id" = 4625
  GROUP BY "computer" 
  HAVING count(*) > 2;

Hope it helps you!